# Two system complex equations with symbolic variables

Tags: equation-solving, complex

I am trying to solve the next problem:

Known values are: $e, z, vo, n_p, n_q, s$

Variable to find: $P_2, Q_2, k_r, k_i$

All them are real values. Then I define the next variables as:

$a_1 = ez$

$a_2 = (1-e)z$

$b_1 = n_pP_2+n_qQ_2j$

$b_2 = P_2 + Q_2j$

$c_1 = vo - (k_r+k_ij)(n_pP_2+n_qQ_2j)$

$c_2 = vo - (k_r+k_ij)(P_2+Q_2j)$

where $j$ is the imaginary factor, then I have these two complex equations:

$0 = (a_1 c_2 + a_2 c_1)(b_1/c_1+b_2/c_2) - a_1 a_2(b_1/c_1+b_2/c_2) \overline{(b_1/c_1 + b_2/c_2)} - z*s$
$0 = b_2 - c_2\left( \overline{(c_2-c_1)/z} + e(b_1/c_1+b_2/c_2)\right)$

*Pd: the overline means conjugate.*

In which the only unknown variables are: $P_2, Q_2, k_r, k_i$

**EDIT :**

Thanks to @user42582, the formulation of the problem in Mathematica is as follows:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]

params = {e, z, v0, np, nq, s};

vars = {P2, Q2, kr, ki};

assums = Element[Join[params, vars], Reals];

rls = {
   a1 -> e z, 
   a2 -> (1 - e) z, 
   b1 -> np P2 + nq Q2 I, 
   b2 -> P2 + Q2 I, 
   c1 -> v0 - (kr + ki I) (np P2 + nq Q2 I), 
   c2 -> v0 - (kr + ki I) (P2 + Q2 I)
 };

eqs = {
   0 == (a1 c2 + a2 c1) (b1/c1 + b2/c2) - a1 a2 (b1/c1 + b2/c2) Conjugate[b1/c1 + b2/c2] - z s, 
   0 == b2 - c2 (Conjugate[(c2 - c1)/z] + e (b1/c1 + b2/c2))
 }/.rls // ComplexExpand;

Reduce[And @@ eqs && assums, vars, Complexes]
```

However, the code keep running for several minutes without giving a solution. Does Mathematica is able to solve this kind of complex-equation system with symbolic variables? is there other way to tackle the problem?. Any help or suggestion will be appreciated!!

Comment: welcome; you are supposed to provide some code for replication purposes and troubleshooting; if you are having trouble formulating your problem in *WL* I'd suggest looking at the following built-in functions/symbols: [`List`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/List.html), [`Set`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Set.html), [`Rule`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rule.html), [`ReplaceAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll.html), [`Element`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Element.html), ...

Comment: ... [`Conjugate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Conjugate.html), [`Imaginary`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/I.html), [`Solve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html), probably [`Reduce`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reduce.html) and [`ComplexExpand`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ComplexExpand.html).

Comment: You cannot solve for four variables with only two equations. Presumably, your known values includes `s`. Start with `$Assumptions = Element[{e, ki, kr, np, nq, P2, Q2, s, v0, z}, Reals];` and then any function that uses the option `Assumptions` (e.g., Simplify, Solve, Reduce) will assume that the variables are real.

Comment: @BobHanlon if you did not notice, two complex equations give 4 real equations and with 4 variables, it can be solved.

Comment: @user42582 I am ashamed to say that I dont even know how to code it using Mathematica, if someone could give me a hand on that, really be thankful I just download that app to solve this equation, only for that.

Comment: @BurNor - yes, my mistake. There are four equations implied.

Answer (score 3):

Let `params` denote a list that collects all the parameters (known values) of the problem ie `params = {e, z, v0, np, nq, P1, Q1}`.

Also, let `vars` bundle together all the variables of the problem `vars = {P2, Q2, kr, ki}`.

Notice that we are *not* going to use sub-scripted variables (eg we use `P2` instead of $P_2$).

It is not impossible to use sub-scripted variables with *Mathematica* / *WL* (eg expressions like `Subscript[P,2]`), in fact it is relatively straightforward to use them, but we are going to take the relatively safe and fast route (please note this is a subjective judgement about what's '*safe*' and '*fast*'; other users might have different opinions on the matter).

After having defined our parameters and our variables, the next thing we need to do is, to define a list of rules that we are going to use, in order to replace the quantities in the equations, with their respective definitions (see below)

```
rls = {
   a1 -> e z, 
   a2 -> (1 - e) z, 
   b1 -> np P2 + nq Q2 I, 
   b2 -> P2 + Q2 I, 
   c1 -> v0 - (kr + ki I) (np P2 + nq Q2 I), 
   c2 -> v0 - (kr + ki I) (P2 + Q2 I)
 };
```

`rls` is a symbol that contains a list of rules.

Rule replacement is a central theme in *Mathematica* / *WL* (perhaps, [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/18706#18706) might be helpful, also please check the relevant links in the comment section of the question).

Effectively, when you pair a replacing rule like eg `x->1` with an expression that contains the symbol `x`, you can *replace all* the instances of `x` in the expression with `1`, eg evaluating

```
ReplaceAll[x^2+x+1, x->1]
```

or

```
x^2+x+1/.x->1
```

should return `3` ( = `1^2+1+1`).

Note how `/.` is the infix notation for `ReplaceAll` (in a similar fashion, it is possible to write addition 'traditionally' `1+1` but also like a function `Plus[1,1]`).

Using rules in the context of the question, is useful in order to transform the equations, from relations that contain the *composite* quantities $a_1,a_2,b_1,b_2,c_1,c_2$, to relations that contain the *parameters* `params` (and variables, `vars`) of the problem.

```
eqs = {
   0 == (a1 c2 + a2 c1) (b1/c1 + b2/c2) - a1 a2 (b1/c1 + b2/c2) Conjugate[b1/c1 + b2/c2] - z s, 
   0 == b2 - c2 (Conjugate[(c2 - c1)/z] + e (b1/c1 + b2/c2))
 }/.rls // ComplexExpand;
```

Evaluating this code will return a long expression that is not replicated here (for the use of `ComplexExpand`, please see [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ComplexExpand.html); also `//` is the postfix way of applying functions, please see [`Postfix`](http://reference.wolfram.com/search/?q=postfix)).

After having reached thus far, the next step is to use one of the built-in functions available to *Mathematica* / *WL* in order to solve the system of equations.

Unfortunately, evaluating

```
Reduce[And @@ eqs && assums, vars, Complexes]
```

or

```
Solve[And @@ eqs && assums, vars, Complexes]
```

(where `assums = Element[Join[params, vars], Reals]`) takes a long time to terminate on my system (I had to abort evaluation);

Therefore, the answer to the first question (whether *Mathematica* can '*solve such equations?*') is uncertain at this point. Perhaps other users can evaluate the relevant expressions and provide more decisive answers.

As far as the other part of the question is concerned ('*could you please give some guide so that I can apply to my system of equations.*'), this answer was a attempt at a (really) fast introduction to the relevant syntax and practical application of the appropriate functions needed to tackle the question in hand.

---

code section for replication purposes

```
params = {e, z, v0, np, nq, P1, Q1};

vars = {P2, Q2, kr, ki};

assums = Element[Join[params, vars], Reals];

rls = {
   a1 -> e z, 
   a2 -> (1 - e) z, 
   b1 -> np P2 + nq Q2 I, 
   b2 -> P2 + Q2 I, 
   c1 -> v0 - (kr + ki I) (np P2 + nq Q2 I), 
   c2 -> v0 - (kr + ki I) (P2 + Q2 I)
 };

eqs = {
   0 == (a1 c2 + a2 c1) (b1/c1 + b2/c2) - a1 a2 (b1/c1 + b2/c2) Conjugate[b1/c1 + b2/c2] - z s, 
   0 == b2 - c2 (Conjugate[(c2 - c1)/z] + e (b1/c1 + b2/c2))
 }/.rls // ComplexExpand;

Reduce[And @@ eqs && assums, vars, Complexes]
```

or

```
Solve[And @@ eqs && assums, vars, Complexes]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for you good explanation, it is very useful, many thanks!! I manage to run the code you provided, but changing `->` to `=` inside the list of rules ( `rls` ). However, I dont get the solution (values of kr, ki, P2, Q2) but this function [link](https://imgur.com/a/aM1b6)

Comment: One quest I have is if with `complexes` you are telling the algorithm that the equations have complex nature, so that internally it can separate real and imaginary components and equal each one to zero in each of the two equations. @user42582

Comment: I think that `Solve` returns unevaluated because when you replaced `->` with `=` you effectively replaced $a_1,a_2,b_1,b_2,c_1,c_2$ with their definitions and that messed with `assums`; try evaluating the code without any modifications and if it's taking too long to finish hold Alt and press . to abort.

Comment: specifying the domain in eg `Solve`instructs the function to '*solve for real values of variables, but function values are allowed to be complex*' (from the documentation of [`Solve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html))

Comment: Another issues is that it seems that the complexity of the problem is a bit much for the software? Do you think it would help if real and imaginary part of these two equations are explicitly separated? How would it be the code structure for that?, I appreciate your support!! @user42582

Answer (score 2):

Continuing the answer of @user42582. You have to use numeric values for the parameters, because there are too much of them to give a general solution with Reduce.

In order to get 4 equations for 4 variables, do ComplexExpand

```
ceRe1 = ComplexExpand[
Re[(a1 c2 + a2 c1) (b1/c1 + b2/c2) - 
   a1 a2 (b1/c1 + b2/c2) Conjugate[b1/c1 + b2/c2] - z s /. rls], 
TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}] // Together;

ceIm1 = ComplexExpand[
Im[(a1 c2 + a2 c1) (b1/c1 + b2/c2) - 
   a1 a2 (b1/c1 + b2/c2) Conjugate[b1/c1 + b2/c2] - z s /. rls], 
TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}] // Together;

ceRe2 = ComplexExpand[
Re[b2 - c2 (Conjugate[(c2 - c1)/z] + e (b1/c1 + b2/c2)) /. rls], 
TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}] // Together;

ceIm2 = ComplexExpand[
Im[b2 - c2 (Conjugate[(c2 - c1)/z] + e (b1/c1 + b2/c2)) /. rls], 
TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}] // Together;

equ[e_, z_, v0_, np_, nq_, P1_, Q1_, s_] = {ceRe1 == 0, ceIm1 == 0, 
    ceRe2 == 0, ceIm2 == 0};
```

With definite parameters `equ[e, z, v0, np, nq, P1, Q1, s]`, lets do numerical solution. It is faster, to look also for complex solutions and later select the real ones.

```
Select[vars /.NSolve[Rationalize[equ[3, 4, 5, -1, -5, -2, -7, 1], 0], vars, 
    WorkingPrecision -> 25], # \[Element] Reals &]

(*    {{-242.5520609774053748529452, 0, -0.2020193436400476926216504, 
         0}, {-4.594775269939857887725161, 0, -0.1417971758148797823998203, 
         0}}    *)
```

Comment: Thanks for you help @Akku14, but I need the system to be solve in the symbolic form, because I want to know the influence of the variables `e, z, v0, np, nq, s` over `kr , ki`. Do you think Mathematica is able to solve this sytem with symbolic variables? can you advice me please.